# Find regex with recursive php

Tags: php, regex, string

I need find regex of follow string, and get all tab parent :

```
{jmstabs type="horizontal" theme="two" nav="left"}
       [tab title="Tab title 1"]Tab content 1[/tab]
       [tab title="Tab title 2"]Tab content 2[/tab]
       [tab title="Tab title 3"]
            {jmstabs}
               [tab title="Tab child 1"]Tab child 1[/tab]
               [tab title="Tab child 2"]Tab child 2[/tab]
            {/jmstabs}
       [/tab]
{/jmstabs}
```

I want to get result after preg_match_all is:

```
 1. [tab title="Tab title 1"]Tab content 1[/tab]
 2. [tab title="Tab title 2"]Tab content 2[/tab]
 3. [tab title="Tab title 3"]
        {jmstabs}
             [tab title="Tab child 1"]Tab child 1[/tab]
             [tab title="Tab child 2"]Tab child 2[/tab]
        {/jmstabs}
    [/tab]
```

Please help me! Thanks everybody.

Comment: Use some kind of parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<item>\s*(?:(?&curly)|(?&square))|[^\[\{]*)
    (?<attr>\s+\w+="[^"]*")
    (?<curly>\{(\w+)(?&attr)*\}(?&item)*\{\/\w+\})
    (?<square>\[(\w+)(?&attr)*\](?&item)*\[\/\w+\])
)\[tab(?&attr)*\](?&item)*\[\/tab\]
```

[Online Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/sF8rW5/1)

Comment: ! Thank you very much ! Work perfect :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rawing's Regex Pattern; below is how you could put those to use. And... by the way; You may check out a Demonstration [here](https://eval.in/623321):

```
<?php

    $str = '{jmstabs type="horizontal" theme="two" nav="left"}
               [tab title="Tab title 1"]Tab content 1[/tab]
               [tab title="Tab title 2"]Tab content 2[/tab]
               [tab title="Tab title 3"]
                   {jmstabs}
                        [tab title="Tab child 1"]Tab child 1[/tab]
                        [tab title="Tab child 2"]Tab child 2[/tab]
                    {/jmstabs}
                [/tab]
            {/jmstabs}';

    preg_match_all("#(?(DEFINE)
                    (?<item>\s*(?:(?&curly)|(?&square))|[^\[\{]*)
                    (?<attr>\s+\w+=\"[^\"]*\")
                    (?<curly>\{(\w+)(?&attr)*\}(?&item)*\{\/\w+\})
                    (?<square>\[(\w+)(?&attr)*\](?&item)*\[\/\w+\])
                )\[tab(?&attr)*\](?&item)*\[\/tab\]#", $str, $matches);


    var_dump( $matches[0] );

    // PRODUCES:::
    array (size=3)
          0 => string '[tab title="Tab title 1"]Tab content 1[/tab]' (length=44)
          1 => string '[tab title="Tab title 2"]Tab content 2[/tab]' (length=44)
          2 => string '[tab title="Tab title 3"]
                           {jmstabs}
                                [tab title="Tab child 1"]Tab child 1[/tab]
                                [tab title="Tab child 2"]Tab child 2[/tab]
                            {/jmstabs}
                        [/tab]' (length=211)
```